# Non-blocking DNS resolution

Tags: c, sockets, networking, dns, network-programming

This is something that came up while messing around a bit trying to build a DNS client/server system...

A function such as `getaddrinfo` or  `gethostbyname` resorts to some sort of DNS resolution to answer queries. I've digged around a lot for source code, but never actually seen a single line of code where a socket is open and communications happen between a DNS server and a client.

My question is this, how do functions such as `gethostbyname` perform a network operation such as a DNS lookup without blocking while reading on a socket etc..? From a user perspective, `gethostbyname` seems almost instantaneous in operation...

Comment: How do you get it does not wait? Did you strace? What is the problem? Did you read the source code of the functions?

Comment: My apologies. It does wait, but it appears to finish very quickly. I'm just curious as to the inner workings of these functions, such as whether they use non-blocking sockets, some sort of IO polling and so on. Source code that I have dug up so far does not even hint at socket operations.

Comment: it's likely that `gethostbyname` and `getaddrinfo` will ultimately end up using the `res_*` functions from `libresolv`, so look for the source for the latter.

Comment: Wiki: 'DNS primarily uses the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) on port number 53 to serve requests'.  So, sockets, UDP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these functions directly return the value you asked for (instead of using a callback or returning a promise) and since DNS lookups take time these functions must obviously block. How fast they are depends on lots of factors, like which DNS server they query (local or remote), if the result is already available in the DNS server (i.e. cached from previous lookup) and how fast the upstream DNS server are which are needed to lookup yet unknown names.

Answer (score 2):

Some WA to async resolving is an using `getaddrinfo_a` with `GAI_NOWAIT` option.

Existing implementation at the glibc uses thread-pool to do requests. And, it simple to implement such functionality for systems without `getaddrinfo_a` support.

Note, that resolving mechanizm does not only operates with DNS servers, it uses, also, `/etc/hosts` (on Windows: `WINDIR/system32/etc/hosts`) and other sources, like mDNS and so on. It can be configured via `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, section `hosts:`.

This functionality provides by the "plugins" for the NSS subsystem, most of them can be found by prefix `libnss_`. DNS resolver, AFAIK, located at the `libnss_dns.so` (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so` on my system), that provides by the glibc (`libc6` package on Linux Mint).

So, you should look into plugin implementation to search operation with network.